# Trying to connect Ubuntu 14.04 wired but can only get local access

Tags: internet, wired

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I cant connect to internet. My setup is wired into a wireless router bridged with another to the internet, it's plug and play on my Windows. Can anyone help?

```
Eth0   Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:12:3f:43:3e:71
       Inet addr:169.254.5.135 Bcast:169.254.255.255 Mask:255.255.0.0
       Inet6 addr:fe80:212:3fff:fe43:3e71:/64 Scope:link
       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
       RX packets:2872 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:362 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       Collisions:0 txqueulen:1000
       RX bytes:291128 (291.1KB) TX bytes:63010 (63.0 KB)
       Interrupt:16

Lo     Link encap:local Loopback
       Inet addr:127.0.0.1 mask:255.0.0.0
       Inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:host
       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
       RX packets:2000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
       TX packets:2000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       Collisions:0 txqueulen:0
       RX bytes:156416 (156.4 KB) TX bytes:156416 (156.4 KB)
```

Comment: Added the output

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Ubuntu but I had this issue at one point.  I went into a terminal session and typed in `ifconfig` and found out that I wasn't set to DHCP for some reason.  Then I edited the appropriate file using [Network Configuration Command Line Instructions Sheet](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine)

The information you added about and IP address of 169.X.X.X means that it is not connecting.  This could mean a bad cable, a bad port in the wall or on the router, etc.  Try a different cable and/or a different port and run it again.  Generally a 169.X.X.X is a hardware failure not a configuration failure.

Good luck!